# In RxJS, how can you get the value that caused an error?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Inside a `.catch()`, how can I find the value that caused the error?

For example, lets say you have code like this:

```
Rx.Observable.of(42)
.map((val) => {
  throw new Error('oops!');
})
.catch((err) => {
  // how can I get `42` here?
});
```

How can you know what ended up causing the error?

For bonus points, is this possibly in `.finally()`?

Comment: What about throwing the value?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the value, pass it in your exception.

```
Rx.Observable.of(42)
.map((val) => {
  throw new AppError({message : 'oops!', contextInfo : {someName: 42}});
})
.catch((err) => {
  // get it from the `err` object
});
```

This requires that you implement your own kind of error (`AppError`) which inherits from the native `Error`. This technique is not specific to `Rxjs` but can be applied everywhere. `Error` is an object, to which you can add any field you see fit through inheritance. It is a good practice to have errors include any relevant info about the when(tracing)/where(blame assignment)/why(diagnostic) aspects of the error.

About how to create your own error, have a look at [Custom_Error_Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Custom_Error_Types).

`finally` operator uses a selector function which does not take any arguments. Hence, if it is possible to do this in `finally`, it will not be through parameter passing. You might still be able to do it through closure, but that is far from being something I would recommend.

**UPDATE**
Referring to `How can you know what ended up causing the error?`, in the general case you can't. Just like with promises, errors are propagated up to where they are caught, or else end up bubbling out of the promise/observable context. So the usual techniques apply, the `fail fast` technique being the most productive :

- fail fast : use a type system (of your own, provided by your language or else) - that way you will ensure you only handle values of the expected type, so you can eliminate those types of errors. I experimented with [a babel plugin for contracts](http://%60https://github.com/codemix/babel-plugin-contracts%60) and I found it quite usable if you already use babel.
- fail fast : catch error as early as you can, the farther you are from the source of the errors, the harder it is to investigate.
- fail fast : use libraries that have good error reporting over those who don't (silent swallowing of errors is your enemy here). Good library will offer a configuration parameter for that purpose.
- check the stack trace (with rxjs 5, it became easier to do this, but you still have to know about the internals)
- add tracing/logging information to your code, etc.

Comment: This doesn't help in situations where the error is not one you created. I am looking for a general purpose solution so I can guarantee references specific to that object are cleaned up if the object has any type of error.

Comment: Then you should provide a more realistic example, so one can understand the general case that you are handling. That said, even if the error is not one you have created, provided it has the `Error` type, you can still catch it and extend it with your local data and rethrow it if that is your use case. In any case, your cleanup must happen in the `catch` clause, it can't happen in the `finally` clause. Can you post a better example?